# OSMNx : get coordinates of nodes using OSM id

Tags: python, openstreetmap, networkx

I used the Python library OSMNx to draw an optimal route between several steps of a city trip. The final variable is [a list of OSM ids](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node).

Now, I'm trying to save this route as a shp or json files. The problem is that I need for that the latitude/longitude of each node, but I didn't found an OSMNx function to do that.

I tried get_route_edge_attributes (but coordinates are not a valid attribute for this function). Is there any way to get coordinates of an OSM node with this single id ?

Comment: My bad Alireza, I was in vacation and far from any screen ! I've just tested your lines and they worked fine. I validate your answer immediately, thank you again.

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment. happy to hear it works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you have all the attribute of each node and edge in the Graph. you can get node attributes using:

```
G.node[38862848]
#out: {'highway': nan,
# 'lat': 45.3210533,
# 'lon': -122.9790558,
# 'osmid': '38862848',
# 'ref': nan,
# 'x': 501641.47862882155,
# 'y': 5018616.5723966481}

G.node[38862848]['lat']
# out: 45.3210533
```

and to get edge attributes you can use `G[u][v]`:

```
G[5035130880][4963510289]
# out: 
#{0: {'bridge': 'yes',
#  'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f90ad7d5860>,
#  'highway': 'secondary',
#  'length': 671.332597496,
#  'name': 'Northwest 185th Avenue',
#  'oneway': False,
#  'osmid': [124454683, 24446714, 124454682]}}
```

All attributes are also in GeoDataFrame's of the graph.
 If you have list of nodes, the easiest way to get the geometry of all nodes is:

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs()
path = nx.shortest_path(G, G.nodes()[0], G.nodes()[1])
gdf_nodes.loc[path]
#out: 
#        highway    lat lon    osmid    ref x   y   geometry    traffic_signals
#5035130880 NaN 45.5637 -122.868    5035130880  NaN 510334  5.04558e+06 POINT (510334.0390091945 5045583.999886028) 0
#4963510289 NaN 45.5698 -122.868    4963510289  NaN 510329  5.04625e+06 POINT (510329.3114555664 5046254.728223645) 0
# ...
```

the output is a GeoDataFrame.

Comment: my G has no .node

Comment: For osmx version 1.1.2 G.nodes works (not G.node)

Answer (score 5):

See also [this](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/340#issuecomment-547021812) on GitHub for more details:

> The `x` and `y` attributes are your node coordinates. If your graph is unprojected, then they are in lat-lon (degree units).
>
> *If you've projected your graph*, then `x` and `y` are your projected node coordinates (in meters or whatever units your projected coordinate system uses) and the nodes will also have additional `lat` and `lon` attributes that contain the original unprojected coordinates.

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')
node_id = list(G.nodes)[0]
G.nodes[node_id]['x'] #lon
G.nodes[node_id]['y'] #lat
```

Comment: For anyone coming here: For me, doing `G.node` results in an error (`'MultiDiGraph' object has no attribute 'node'`). You need to use the plural: `nodes` e.g. `G.nodes[node_id]['x']` should work.

Comment: Thanks. The networkx API has changed over the intervening months.

Comment: so what now instead of `.node`?

Comment: i found out how, nodes = g.nodes(), info = nodes[some_id]

Comment: @tmo, I think you should convert your comment into an answer. I only saw it after I found the answer by myself.

Comment: Added it as an answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**G.node[38862848]['y']** for latitude and
**G.node[38862848]['x']** for longitude

Comment: my G has no .node

Answer (score 2):

**28-01-2021** update

After a update of the NetworkX API, notice that you need to **use the plural**: *nodes* e.g.

```
G.nodes[node_id]['x']
```

should work.

Doing G.node results in an error ('MultiDiGraph' object has no attribute 'node').