# Get coordinates of nodes using OSM id's

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I am new to OSM API, I want to get the coordinates using OSM id. In this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46238813/osmnx-get-coordinates-of-nodes-using-osm-id) I didn't get how to create the graph G as I am a beginner. I am using python to get the response from OSM API.
for example, when we access this link with the proper id: https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/1989098258, we get an xml response containing all we want !
Could you give me a good example of how to use node API please ?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to get an information about a given OSM node.
First install `osmapi` package using `pip3`:

```sh
pip3 install osmapi
```

then for example a node `id=1989098258`
we do

```py
import osmapi as osm
api = osm.OsmApi() # this instantiate the OsmApi class,
# it has many function, we will use NodeGet function.
# For more detail about it check the doc
# http://osmapi.metaodi.ch/#osmapi.OsmApi.OsmApi.NodeGet
node = api.NodeGet(1989098258)
node # will return a dict object
```

object `node` returns:

```
{'id': 1989098258,
 'visible': True,
 'version': 2,
 'changeset': 16442326,
 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 6, 10, 11, 58),
 'user': 'wambacher',
 'uid': 201359,
 'lat': 24.3655948,
 'lon': 88.6279164,
 'tag': {}}
```

then to get longitude and latitude of node do:

```py
node["lon"] # get longitude
node["lat"] # get latitude
```

Comment: Notice that the OSM API is for editing the map, not for general data processing. Read the terms of use here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API#Terms_of_use . You may want to look at the Overpass API, or at using downloaded database extracts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am getting node id from xml file, I parse it and I get `lon` and `lat` from each node. Why would I download a database ?

Comment: When you do api.NodeGet, you are sending requests to the OSM editing servers. You should avoid doing that, unless you are actually editing the map.

Comment: Ah ok didn't pay attention thanks, do you know any other alternative to read OSM data ?

Comment: If you intent do perform a large number of queries against this API then better download an extract and perform your queries locally. As already suggested by @TurePålsson.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @scai. I m not doing a large number of queries, it was just for test purpose.